# GNU Make pattern rule depending on non-pattern file

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

In GNU Make, what exactly are the semantics of a pattern rule that depends on a non-pattern file?

I have the following snippet in a Makefile. When `foo.a` exists, GNU Make doesn't seem to create `foo.b` when `make foo.b` is called.

```
.SUFFIXES:

%.b: move_a_to_b.artifact

move_a_to_b.artifact:
        mv foo.a foo.b
        touch move_a_to_b.artifact
```

The following, however, works fine and moves the file from `foo.a` to `foo.b`.

```
.SUFFXIES:

%.b: %.a
        mv $< $@
```

As does this, with a pattern rule depending on a pattern rule

```
.SUFFIXES:

%.b: %.intermediate
        mv $< $@

%.intermediate: %.a
        mv $< $@
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't have anything to do with pattern rules depending on non-patterns.  That's fine and it has the expected semantics: for any file ending in `.b` if it's out of date with respect to the file `move_a_to_b.artifact` then the recipe will be run.

Your issue is that you're not defining a pattern rule, you're *deleting* a pattern rule.  A pattern rule *must always* have a recipe.  A pattern rule without a recipe deletes the pattern rule.  See [Canceling Pattern Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Canceling-Rules.html).

You have to add a recipe, then it will do something:

```
%.b : move_a_to_b.artifact
        @echo do something to create $@
```

Comment: I thought it had something to do with a pattern target depending on a non pattern prerequisite. But you proved otherwise. Thank you for clearing that confusion up! :-)

Comment: `%.b : move_a_to_b.artifact ;` will work too for an explicit empty recipe.